# Citing in Texstudio gives jibberish symbols in autocomplete citation commands

Tags: biblatex, citing, texstudio, biber, auto-completion

When I cite in Texstudio, the bibtex keys appear as jibberish and renders unusable in the autocomplete command in TexStudio, see attached figure. My .bib and .tex files are encoded in UTF-8 according to the Texstudio editor. I use Jabref in association with Texstudio, and Miktex as Tex distribution.

The weird thing is, is that it worked perfectly before i reinstalled Windows 10 this weekend. No changes have been done to the files as far as i know. I deleted the auxiliary files without it solving the problem.

Thank you for your help!

[image: Texstudio \parencite command with bibtex key jibberish]

Answer (score 2):

OK, I figured it out as soon as i posted the question, but other people may benefit from it (delete it otherwise).

In Texstudio, the bibliography wasn't set to UTF-8 (in Adv. Editor tab), probably causing the strange effect to occur. by changing it to UTF-8 and saving the preset, the problem disappeared.